# How to iterate over dict keys when assigning values to multiple variables

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a multi-dim dict with primary key being a hash and sub values keyed on single chars.  I'm trying to assign a subset of values to multiple vars by iterating over a string containing the chars of the sub-keys I want.  Something like:

```
A,B,C = tree[hash][i] for i in "xyz"
```

This would equate to:

```
A = tree[hash]["x"]
B = tree[hash]["y"]
C = tree[hash]["z"]
```

But trying to do it all in a single line, possibly to imbed in a function where I would pass the list of vars and the corresponding string of sub-keys.

Comment: Do the following `A,B,C = [tree[hash][i] for i in "xyz"]`

Comment: _If hash is a variable name, please consider changing it to another name like `hash_val` or simply just a trailing underscore._

Comment: do you always have a fixed number of receiving variables vs subkeys?  i.e. abc and xyz are both 3?

Comment: second @NChauhan remark.  hash is a builtin function and your variable name hides it.  hash_ avoids that and the trailing _ is often used in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tree[hash][i] for i in "xyz"` is already a generator comprehension, but it needs to be parenthesized unless it's passed as sole argument of a function like this:

```
my_function(tree[hash][i] for i in "xyz")   # this is valid
my_function(tree[hash][i] for i in "xyz", 12)   # this is invalid, parsing conflict
my_function((tree[hash][i] for i in "xyz"), 12)   # this is valid
```

This is the same with your assignment expression. The parentheses are needed to avoid ambiguity when parsing.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52570514/6451573) solves the issue, but is creating an unnecessary list when a generator comprehension is enough:

```
A, B, C = (tree[hash][i] for i in "xyz")
```

Unpacking assigns left hand variables by iterating on the generator comprehension without creating an unnecessary list.

Also maybe avoid hashing 3 times, use a variable

```
h = tree[hash]
A, B, C = (h[i] for i in "xyz")
```

variant with `map` and `operator.itemgetter` to avoid loops:

```
import operator
A,B,C = map(operator.itemgetter(tree[hash]),"xyz")
```

Aside: avoid `hash` as a variable name, since it's the built-in function to hash objects.

Comment: That is smooth. I should have thought about it

Comment: listcomp or gencomp, I don't think it makes a big difference for 3 arguments anyway.

Comment: Yes it doesn't but I feel if we are not iterating list more than once than gencomp would always be preferable

Comment: Discovered the problem when one of they keys is not present, so use this instead:
A,B,C = (tree[hash].get(i) for i in "xyz")

Comment: @angrysumit there are times where passing a list comprehension is better, for instance when using `str.join`

Comment: @MichaelB you mean this `(h.get(i,0) for i in "xyz")` ? so 0 is issued if key is missing? yeah okay, but now one of A, B, and C is 0 or `None` and the code will break a little later, unless this is expected.

Answer (score 5):

You have nearly done that. Just add square brackets around right side expression. It's called list comprehension:

```
A, B, C = [tree[hash][i] for i in "xyz"]
```

Comment: "I can't comment due to low points so please bear with me.": no, not anymore. Anyway, the answer is fine, no need to apologise.

Comment: @MichaelB, preferred ways to say "Thanks" in SO is voting up and accept the answer (click on the check mark near the answer). This answer is still not accepted from you.